# Ruby gem for unix 'at' command

Tags: ruby, unix, rubygems

I've found the [whenever](http://github.com/javan/whenever) gem quite useful for working with `cron` from Ruby.  Does anyone know of a similar project for `at`/`batch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rat, at http://github.com/koops/rat

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be run by 'at'? Otherwise you could check out [delayed_job](http://github.com/tobi/delayed_job).

Comment: NO, Hold on delayed Job still uses database poling.  I don't need to check the database every 5 seconds for something that happens 3-4 time a **week**.

Comment: Sure but you didn't really tell us it happens that seldom.